# How do I move existing notes from my iCloud to another folder (gmail, etc)?

Tags: icloud, gmail, notes.app

I was looking for some help.  I have a mac and an iPhone.  I have 200 important notes in my icloud.  I am scared that something will happen to my phone or mac and I will lose all my notes because my icloud is not backed up.  I am looking for a way to relocate all of my notes to something more universal that does not need to be backed up (Gmail).

Comment: Why do you think that data in iCloud might be lost if not backed up, but Gmail doesn’t need to be backed up? They’re basically the same thing, cloud services run by large companies.

Comment: @Mike Scott is correct. But to answer your question can’t you just drag n’ drop them in Notes.app on your Mac?

Comment: Think this article could answer your question
https://www.imyfone.com/back-up-iphone/how-to-backup-notes-on-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your notes are backed up in iCloud. Go to iCloud.com and you should be able to see them all there.
2. If you are more comfortable storing them in Google, you can:

   - Enable notes under accounts (under your Google account) on both devices
   - Cut and paste the actual text in your iCloud notes into new notes within Google on the notes app. You can’t just drag them over unfortunately.